# yii2 multiple insert not working

Tags: php, html, yii2

Multiple insert is not working. Here my code

**View:**

```
 <?php echo  $form->field($model_sup, 'ddDate')- >textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Date','id'=>'datepicker1'))?>

 <?php echo  $form->field($model_sup, 'intBillNo')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Bill No'))?>

 <?php echo $form->field($model_sup, 'varSuppliercode')->textInput(array('placeholder'=>'Supplier Code','id'=>'project'))?>


 <?php echo  $form->field($model_sup, 'varSalesname')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Sales name','id'=>'project_bill'))?>


 <?php echo  $form->field($model_sup, 'varSuppliername')->textarea(array('placeholder' => 'Supplier name','id'=>'bill_page'))?>

 <?php echo  $form->field($model_sup, 'varAreaname')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Area name'))?>

 <?php echo  $form->field($model_sup, 'varAddress')->textarea(array('placeholder' => 'Address','id'=>'project-description_bill'))?>

 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover total_table add_tr">
 <thead>
 <tr>
<th width="14%">Code</th>
<th width="20%">Product Name</th>
<th width="15%">Quantity</th>
 <th width="14%">Price</th>
 <th width="14%">Free Qty/ Rs/</th>
 <th width="20%">Amount</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td><?php echo  $form->field($model_pro, 'intProductcode')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Product code','id'=>'project_bill_pro'))->label('Product code')?></td>
<td><?php echo  $form->field($model_pro, 'varProductname')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Product name','id'=>'project-description_bill_pro'))->label('Product name')?></td>
<td class="two_sec"><?php echo  $form->field($model_pro, 'intQuantity_box')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Box'))->label('Quantity')?>
<?php echo  $form->field($model_pro, 'intQuantity')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Quantity','id'=>'quantity'))?>
</td>
<td><?php echo  $form->field($model_pro, 'fltPrice')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Price','id'=>'project-price_bill_pro'))->label('Price')?></td>
<td class="two_sec"><?php echo  $form->field($model_pro, 'fltDiscount')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Discount','id'=>'discount'))->label('Discount')?>
</td>
<td><?php echo  $form->field($model_pro, 'fltAmount')-  >textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Amount','id'=>'tot_amount'))->label('Amount')?></td>
</tr>


 </tbody>
 </table>

 <div id="container">
 <div class="col-sm-4"><button class="addmore" type="button"      id="add_field">+ Add More</button></div>
 <div class="col-sm-2 border_right_no"><label>Total:</label></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $amount; ?

 <?php echo Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'button-cus', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
```

**Model:**

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ['intProductcode', 'required'],
        ['intBillNo', 'safe'],
        ['varSuppliercode', 'safe'],
        ['varProductname', 'required'],
        ['intQuantity', 'required'],
        ['intQuantity_box', 'required'],
        ['fltPrice', 'required'],
        ['fltDiscount', 'required'],
        ['fltAmount', 'required'],          
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
$model_sup = new CustomerDetails();
$model_pro = new ProductDetails();
#####To get the form values in the post method
$postData = Yii::$app->request->post();
if ($model_sup->load($postData) && $model_pro->load($postData) && $model_sup->validate() && $model_pro->validate()){
    if($model_sup->save()){         
        ##### To get the last insert id 
        $id = Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID();
        #### to save the usertype
        $usertype_id = CustomerDetails::findOne($id);
        $user_type_id = $usertype_id->varSuppliercode;
        $user_type_id_id = $usertype_id->intBillNo;
    }                   
    $model_pro->varSuppliercode = $user_type_id;    
    $model_pro->intBillNo = $user_type_id_id;
    $model_pro->save();
    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('succ', 'Bill report added successfully');                    
    return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect('/stock_management/site/view_bill_report');   
}
```

Using Add more button in my view file for save the multiple record. on `click` event of the button write the function. In function I can append the above mention fields.

After Executing the following error will appear

> Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
>       PDOStatement::bindValue() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given
>       Failed to prepare SQL: INSERT INTO `tbl_receipt` (`intProductcode`,   `varProductname`, `intQuantity_box`, `intQuantity`, `fltPrice`, `fltDiscount`, `fltAmount`, `intBillNo`, `varSuppliercode`) VALUES (:qp0, :qp1, :qp2, :qp3, :qp4, :qp5, :qp6, :qp7, :qp8)

Comment: Please add more info... The fact that a db exception is thrown means there is something wrong but the exception contains **what** is actually wrong.

Comment: I can set the form field as array in the view file after clicking the button the new row will show after fill the two rows and click the submit button the error was displayed.If i remove the array symbol [] from the view file next to the firld name it was inserted but the last row is inserted not the first.

Comment: So you have two models in the same view, right? Can you post the complete view code?